# Get Table after Button Click BeautifulSoup Python

Tags: python, selenium, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape a table from the following site :

```
    http://www.boursakuwait.com.kw/Stock/StkHData.aspx?STK=103
```

This is the following code that am using

```
    ap = argparse.ArgumentParser()

    ap.add_argument("--id",required = True, help = "enter the id")
    ap.add_argument("--from",required = True, help = "From date")
    ap.add_argument("--to",required = True, help = "To date")

    args = vars(ap.parse_args())

    id_num = args["id"]
    from_date = args["from"]
    to_date = args["to"]

    browser = webdriver.Firefox()
    url1 = "http://www.boursakuwait.com.kw/Stock/StkHData.aspx?STK=" + id_num

    browser.get(url1)

    elem = browser.find_element_by_id("ContentMatter_txtFrom")
    elem.send_keys(from_date)
    elem = browser.find_element_by_id("ContentMatter_txtTo")
    elem.send_keys(to_date)
    elem = browser.find_element_by_id("ContentMatter_Button1").click()

    time.sleep(5)

    parsed = requests.get(url1)

    soup = BeautifulSoup(parsed.text,'html.parser')
    tble = soup.findAll("table",attrs={"class":"hoverTable"})

    print(tble)
```

After entering the from and to date, and simulating the button click, my goal is obtain the resulting table. However, the code does not recognize the table. I have tried other forms of the code as well **(looping through rows and cols)**, but they haven't worked either.

My guess is that the url doesn't get updated, since it is a **hoverTable**. Is there a way to obtain the table in this case?

P.S: the id_num are integers, 101,102,103 etc. displaying the respective stocks of the companies. The link pasted comes with id 103. **STK=103**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solve it, by using the browser object. Replacing

```
    parsed = requests.get(url1)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(parsed.text,'html.parser')
```

with

```
    parsed = browser.page_source
    soup = BeautifulSoup(parsed,'html.parser')
```

since the browser object carried the state of the url from the beginning instead of the requests used, in between.

A easier way to get the table was suggested by Murthy

```
    tble = soup.select("table.hoverTable")
```

The original code works as well.

Comment: Please don't forget to come back and accept this as the answer when you are allowed. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

you try with the following code.

```
soup.select("table.hoverTable") //to select the table
```

Comment: this worked as well. the real issue however, was with the requests. I was able to solve it by using "browser.page_source". Since the browser object carried the updated table, and the requests did not.